# Ember computed property to return first X number of items from list

Tags: ember.js

I have a one-to-many relationship (using Ember Data). All I want to do is **list the first `N` number of items from that relationship** in an overview (index) template. I'm trying to use the [`Array.slice`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_slice) method but it doesn't seem to return anything at all.

Here's what I have right now:

**models/account.js**

```
// Account model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:   DS.attr('string'),
  notes:  DS.hasMany('note', { async: true })
});
```

**models/note.js**

```
// Note model
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  body:     DS.attr('string'),
  date:     DS.attr('number'), // unix timestamp
  account:  DS.belongsTo('account', { async: true })
});
```

**controllers/account/index.js**

```
// account/index controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  firstNotes: function() {
    return this.get('notes').slice(0,2);
  }.property('notes')
});
```

**templates/account/index.hbs**

```
{{!-- this lists all the associated `Notes` --}}
{{#each notes}}
  {{date}}<br>
  {{body}}
{{/each}}


{{!-- this doesn't list anything!!?? --}}
{{#each firstNotes}}
  {{date}}<br>
  {{body}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out just as I was about to post it so I figured I'd answer it...

All I was missing was a `@each` in the computed property dependency. So it works as expected with this:

```
firstNotes: function() {
   return this.get('notes').slice(0,2);
}.property('notes.@each')
```

Simple.